# Regular Expression to Deterministic Finite Automata

Tags: regex, finite-automata, dfa, state-diagram

How would you convert this RE to a DFA?

```
(a+aab)*b
```

I'm having trouble drawing the state diagram for this one. I'm not sure where to start, especially with the arbitrary number of a's involved.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @Allan Not quite. But I think I figured it out myself.

Answer (score 1):

it does not respect exactly the proper format for `DFA` but you can use the following (very bad) drawing as a starting point.

In order to respect the standard format, you can move each letter to the curves/lines pointing to the rectangle containing it and replace the letters in the rectangles by the state numbers `q1, q2, q3,` etc. (this should be straightforwards)

[image]
Good luck!